# Tool in WoW to find a compatible guild based on a profile

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there currently a tool available on the web where I can put in my character information, times I like to raid, what kind of content I am looking to raid and/or whether I PvP, and guild leaders across the board can contact me via? I am willing to pay the cost of changing servers for the right guild. Blindly transferring to another server is too costly so I was wondering if there is an effective tool out there for finding a good guild. I see WoW Progress is out there, but I'm not sure how often that is used to contact individual players. Also, it doesn't allow me to enter my character if I'm already in a guild, which is a show stopper. I am not entirely ready to leave the guild I'm in now unless something better comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Guild Finder](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/2657799) tool does exist in-game, but it is not widely used, since many people believe you have to be guild-less to use it.  You can bring it up using the `/gf` command.  There are some external resources, though.  Blizzard hosts a [Guild Recruitment Forum](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/1011639/) on their own site that is pretty widely used and is probably your best bet to find a match just by looking through the threads until you find something good.  There are a couple other forums for guild recruitment, such as the [Elitist Jerks forums](http://elitistjerks.com/f59/), [MMO-Champion](http://www.mmo-champion.com/forums/244-Guild-Recruitment), or [TankSpot](http://www.tankspot.com/forumdisplay.php?94-Guild-Recruitment).

There are also some standalone websites, but I'm not sure about their quality.

- [Guildster](http://www.guildster.com)
- [Wowmatcher](http://www.wowmatcher.com/)
- [Wowstead](http://www.wowstead.com/guild-recruitment)

P.S. - If you're looking for a PvP guild, I'd recommend checking on [Arena Junkies](http://www.arenajunkies.com/forum/62-guild-recruitment/).

Comment: According to http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2483689459#10 and others I've read, you can type /gf or /guildfinder to bring it up at any time, you can be guilded or unguilded. So your statement above is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, hey look at that. I had never heard of that option.  As the guy said in the post below that blue post, nobody ever mentioned that.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Also if you don't get any bites from the guild recuitment forum on us.blizzard.net, try the individual realm forums that you belong to and put a LF Guild post there. Sometimes guilds don't bother to read the other forums on us.blizzard.net. Personally I only read class forums on there.

Comment: True, realm forums are also good. Although they seem to have really died out recently.  That might just be my realm though.